# Excel Error 1004 when referencing ranges with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

Greetings Stack Overflow, so I've gone through a lot of potential solutions for this issue and ultimately am having an experience where no matter what sheet in my workbook i decide to reference I receive the Error 1004 message. This is getting rather frustrating and was wondering if anyone here may know what causes this.

```
'This subroutine will delete the old Report Worksheets and create the new ones which we will have the updated data on what was found.
Sub Create_ReportSheets()
    Dim rPI As Range
    Dim rFI As Range
    Dim rUI As Range

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Passed Inputs").Delete
    Sheets("Failed Inputs").Delete
    Sheets("Unmatched Inputs").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Add & Config the new "Pased Inputs" sheet.
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Rule Tables")).Name = "Passed Inputs"
    Set rPI = Sheets("Passed Inputs").Range("A0:B0")
```

The Line below is what is throwing the error. I've tried restarting excel and testing this in a new Workbook and have had no success. Previously lines that I've used to define ranges which run cannot be re executed elsewhere, if i try to copy them somewhere else it begins throwing this error.

```
Set rPI = Sheets("Passed Inputs").Range("A0:B0")
```

Comment: Rows begin at 1.  There is no Row zero

Comment: There is no cell A0 or B0.Try A1 and B1 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Set rPI = Sheets("Passed Inputs").Range("A0:B0")
```

Use:

```
Set rPI = Sheets("Passed Inputs").Range("A:B") to select the 2 complete columns.
```

Comment: This on top of what Tim Williams and NinjaLlama were saying, i can't believe i didn't think about this. I was focused on a syntax error rather than an out of range error.